# SimpleCove coverage not coming for only some models

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, simplecov

I am having very weird issue with simple cov and rspec. 
I have following in my rails_hlper file

```
require 'simplecov'

SimpleCov.start 'rails' do
  add_filter "app/helpers/"
  add_filter "app/models/concerns/"
  add_group 'Models', 'app/models'
end
```

Even if try to run that model's spec its not showing in coverage report.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed by moving above code to top of the `rails_helper.rb` file

Comment: Thanks. I was facing a similar issue. In my case, the issue got fixed by moving the `Simplecov` related `require` statement and `start` statement to the top of the `rails_helper.rb` instead of `spec_helper.rb` file.